# What is Varonis and what does it have to do with SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-server, varonis

Can anyone provide me with some information on what Varonis is and what it has to do with SharePoint?

Thank you.

Comment: http://bfy.tw/8WPc

Comment: Yes I did that, thank you. ;) I was just hoping someone could give me a little more info here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can point Varonis to target your Sharepoint server or web applications to find out detailed permission matrices of your environment.

The DatAdvantage tool allows you to crawl for sensitive data, (eg credit card numbers, personally identifiable information) or certain non-business file types (eg mp3) across your whole environment. It then tells you where this information is, who has access to it and what would happen if you changed access before committing.

You can also choose a particular user and see where they have access permissions across the farm. You can also manage permissions and AD groups from Varonis.

It also acts as a security measure in that the analytics tool can track abnormal patters of users, eg a soon-to-be-leaver who is downloading local copies of sensitive data or an angry admin who deletes vital business information. Every action becomes auditable and tracked.

Business users become the Data Owners of their information and subscription reports can be regularly emailed to them, showing who has access to their locations.

Really useful tool - I've just got my hands on it so still don't know a lot but I can see the potential.

Answer (score 1):

A third party product with which you can monitor SharePoint and User activity. See: https://www.varonis.com/products/datadvantage/office-365/